# "Other storage" taking up most of hard drive

Tags: macos, storage, disk-space

I am having an issue on my wife's MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.5 (late 2012 13-inch retina). The hard drive is only 120 GB, but the "other" category in the About this Mac storage option is taking up over 81 GB. I've tried following a number of turorials online including cleaning up mail cache, downloads, browser cache, etc. to little avail.

My question is, is this expected? I feel like 81 GB for other storage is a bit excessive, but I can't find any files large enough to indicate this should be an issue (including browsing almost her entire user directory and looking at folder sizes).

Anything you could offer would help.

Answer (score 0):

Other storage could refer to anything that OS X doesn't recognize as one of the storage categories (music, videos...) In order to find the source of the files, I would recommend checking the size of folders to determine where large files are. In order to see the size of a folder, right click it and click "get info". You should be able to use this to locate the source of the problem.